# To print a string inside a third party jar in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a java program which uses ojdbc8.jar file.. I am getting "Mismatch with the server cert DN" while i connect to a database. Though there is no mismatch between the client passed and from server , i am getting this error.
There is a class DNVerfier inside ojdbc8.jar and a method verifyConfiguredDN() in it. I need to print the strings that are passed on to this method so that i can see where there is a mismatch..

Is there any way i can print those values coming inside the jar using a sysout and how to do it?

Comment: “there is no mismatch between the client passed and from server…” How do you know that?

Comment: You can probably just debug the code in eclipse or something. although, i remember oracle was kind enough not to include the source code...

Comment: Is it possible your Oracle database uses SSL encryption? And the certificate installed on the server contains a distinguished name (DN) that does not match the hostname you are connecting to with the client?

Comment: Java was built from the ground up to properly support debugging. Use your IDE to debug the code, setting a break point at the method in question.

Comment: The problem is i cant use IDE as i can run the code only on a unix box as there is a firewall restriction.how to debug in this case

Answer (score 0):

use jdb to debug the program from command line

jdb -sourcepath src (if you have the source of jar/or try decompiled classes) yourclass